# Photos library won't open unless I rename it

Tags: ssd, photos.app, error

My system photo library is stored on an external SSD, and is synced to iCloud. All worked fine until I upgraded my M1 MacBook Pro to Ventura, which also upgraded the photo library version.

Now whenever I try to open the library in Photos, I'm shown the "Updating library" screen, and immediately get a dialog saying "the library could not be opened". The error number varies, but most recently it was 4103.

If I attempt to repair the library, the process hangs at about 90% and never completes. But if I kill all running photo processes (photolibraryd, photoanalysisd, cloudphotod, com.apple.photo), then rename the library on disk, it will open just fine. That keeps it happy for a day or two, before I have to rename the library again.

Any idea what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: Same situation with me. I think that iphoto on M1 macbook are corrupting iphoto libraries on external disk.